# Split schedule information (start & end time) into smaller intervals

Tags: python, time-series

I want to take a list of associate work schedules (which include Activity Date, UserID, Activity, Activity Start Date/Time, Activity End Date/Time) and break it up into 30 minute intervals starting on the hour and half hour and list the total time for that activity included in that interval.

Given...

```py
>>> print(df)
activity_date   user_id activity    activity_start_time activity_end_time
11-Jun  bob phones  06/11/2019 8:00 06/11/2019 9:00
11-Jun  bob break   06/11/2019 9:00 06/11/2019 9:15
11-Jun  bob phones  06/11/2019 9:15 06/11/2019 11:15
11-Jun  bob lunch   06/11/2019 11:15    06/11/2019 12:15
```

I'd like this to be the result...

```py
>>> print(df)
interval_start  time_in_interval activity_date  user_id activity    activity_start_time activity_end_time
06/11/2019 8:00 30  11-Jun  bob phones  06/11/2019 8:00 06/11/2019 9:00
06/11/2019 8:30 30  11-Jun  bob phones  06/11/2019 8:00 06/11/2019 9:00
06/11/2019 9:00 15  11-Jun  bob break   06/11/2019 9:00 06/11/2019 9:15
06/11/2019 9:00 15  11-Jun  bob phones  06/11/2019 9:15 06/11/2019 11:15
06/11/2019 9:30 30  11-Jun  bob phones  06/11/2019 9:15 06/11/2019 11:15
06/11/2019 10:00    30  11-Jun  bob phones  06/11/2019 9:15 06/11/2019 11:15
06/11/2019 10:30    30  11-Jun  bob phones  06/11/2019 9:15 06/11/2019 11:15
06/11/2019 11:00    30  11-Jun  bob phones  06/11/2019 9:15 06/11/2019 11:15
06/11/2019 11:30    30  11-Jun  bob phones  06/11/2019 9:15 06/11/2019 11:15
06/11/2019 12:00    15  11-Jun  bob phones  06/11/2019 9:15 06/11/2019 11:15
```

2 new columns (interval start & time in interval) plus new rows added so activities show up appropriately in every interval. I still want to see the original Activity Start & End Times

edit:
this is what I have so far. It will...

- create table of all intervals (every 30 minutes).
- merge with list of userid-dates to create table of all intervals for all dates a userid had a schedule
- merge that with original data frame.

At that point I have a table with all intervals for all userids and the interval where the activity starts is correctly labeled. But if the activity doesn’t start on the interval (e.g. the activity starts at 9:15 instead of 9:00 or 9:30) then the interval start time is null. And all intermediate intervals are there but null (e.g activity that starts at 9;00 and runs until 10:00... the 9:30 interval is listed but the activity info is null

What’s left...

- if interval start time is null (so activity doesn’t start on the hour or half hour) update it with correct interval start time. I have a function for that
- sort by userid, activity start time, interval time and cooy activity info down to fill in activity info (e.g. take info for 9:00-10:00 activity and update 9:30 interval)

I just know there must be a better way....

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime


from pandas import Series, DataFrame

# 
# insert code to a create dataframe as df
# df has schedule data as documented elsewhere
#

#Create interval List
interval_list = list(range(0, 48))
start_of_day = datetime(2019,1,1,0,0,0)
interval_times = pd.DataFrame()
for x in interval_list:
    minutes_into_day = x * 30
    start_of_interval =  (start_of_day + timedelta(minutes=minutes_into_day)).time()
    interval_times = interval_times.append(pd.DataFrame({'interval_start': start_of_interval, 'joiner': 'joiner'}, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)
interval_times['joiner'] = 'joiner'

#Create id_date List
id_date = df.groupby(['user_id', 'date'], as_index=False)['activity'].count().copy()
id_date = id_date.drop('activity', axis=1)
id_date['joiner'] = 'joiner'
id_date

#merge Interval & ID_date
user_ids_interval_date_times = pd.merge(interval_times, id_date)
user_ids_interval_date_times['activity_start_time'] = user_ids_interval_date_times.apply(lambda r : pd.datetime.combine(r['date'],r['interval_start']),1)

#merge with df 
df_temp = pd.merge(df, user_ids_interval_date_times, how='outer')

#if interval is null, then update with interval floor
def floor_dt(dt, delta):
    return datetime.datetime.min + math.ceil((dt - datetime.datetime.min) / delta) * delta - delta



#Sort by ID & activity_start_time

#copy everything down


df_temp
```

Comment: Interesting. What have you achieved so far?

Comment: edited original post with code to date.

I just know there has to be a better way.